# Is IE Collection reliable tool for testing with various versions of Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, browser, cross-browser

On my Windows machine -- I typically test different versions of Internet Explorer using an array of Virtual Machine instances (which obviously requires a fair amount of investment in time and money). In a pinch I have also used IETester -- which at times can be a little unreliable.

However, I just discovered [IE Collection](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm) and was wondering if people have used it -- and can I rely on it for web page testing purposes?

Would love to know what you think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE isn't designed to be installed side-by-side with other versions.  Most of these "all-in-one" testing tools use a trick of the Windows loader that lets you override system DLLs with DLLs in a local directory.  Then they package up a random subset of Windows DLLs from different operating system versions and different IE versions and drop them into some UI.  The fact that they happen to seem to work in this manner is a coincidence and not reliable.  There will be errors and other strangeness, and probably crashes if your target operating system is far enough from the IE version (e.g. IE6 on Win7) and your webpage is significantly complex.

So, to be clear, no, don't use these tools because you can't rely on them to give you an accurate result.  If you want to know how your page looks in a given IE version, use the IE App Compat VHDs available free from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en).

Comment: IECollection should be safe. I've used it for several years without any problems. Well it craches sometimes but otherwise works very well. Please read http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/02/reliable-cross-browser-testing-part-1-internet-explorer/

Comment: IETester is **not** reliable however

Answer (score 4):

Recently (January 2013) Microsoft released a website called http://www.modern.ie/ to deal with testing with different versions of IE, even on different OSes.

It is based on having different VMs targeting the enviroment you want to test (e.g. IE8 on Win7), so you need to choose the type of OS and Virtualization Platform you want to use and then download the VM image.

It seems to be a lot more reliable that IE collection as you are testing the full browser stack.

Answer (score 2):

No, I would not rely on it - at least not completely (i.e. use it just for quick IE tests, but still retest everything later in a reliable solution).

There are differences when testing both with IETester and IECollection, most notably in Javascript processing.

See a similar thread here:
https://superuser.com/questions/118069/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-multiple-versions-of-ie-and-firefox-on-the-same/

From the few answers there, the most viable solutions are virtual machines (which you are using already), or web services which do the testing for you (although these might not be suitable for everyone, i.e. due to data confidentiality).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with IECollection is that it won't install IE6 nor IE7 in a Windows 7 environment, a better solutions could be to use Virtual PC like this: http://blog.donavon.com/2009/08/run-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-side-by-side-on.html

Comment: Best solution I think is to install xp and win7 on virtual mashine and IECollection