# rotate image with jquery compatible with IE7/8

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, jquery-animate, rotation

I have tried so many ways/plugins, and the one that attracts me the most is [jquery.rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

But, it doesn't work (at least for me) in Internet Explorer 7 and 8 (the images just disappear).

My objective is to hover images and make them animate their rotation, it works in Safari + Firefox but not IE.

Is there a way to achieve this and be compatible with most browsers and IE 7 and 8?

**EDIT**: In the end it turns out that both jQuery Rotate and Raphaël do work in IE 7 and 8! I didn't have a chance to test them on a real IE until today. I was testing both on IE Collection (http://utilu.com/IECollection/) and they definitely don't work in those emulated IEs, bummer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jqueryrotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples) works for me, but as an alternative..

Try cssSandpaper: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/

The most relevant demo I could find: http://www.useragentman.com/tests/cssSandpaper/countdown.html

---

*As an aside:*
[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) works just fine in IE7/8, and [is definitely capable of rotating an image.](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html)

> Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+,
>   Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Comment: I will consider your answer valid, although in the end this is a no-issue, since both jQuery Rotate & Raphaël (as you said) work in IE 7 + 8. Anyway, thanks for sharing the csssandpaper link!

Answer (score 0):

Raphael is a great library that works in IE (with VML) and other browsers (with SVG). It can rotate images and deal with transparency.

http://raphaeljs.com/

**Internet Explorer 6, 7 & 8**

http://www.deepbluesky.com/asx/ie8.jpg

Comment: I already tried it and it doesn't work with my IE 7 + 8, I'm starting to think that my IEs are corrupted... A JS error says "object expected"

Comment: Check the include 
Its only when there is some problem with the include the "object expected" error is thrown

Comment: But I'm browsing the oficial link (the one you provided), it works in other browsers.

Comment: The thing is that support isnt there for older versions of IE thats why

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Comment: Please read my request, I need to rotate an image in a way that is compatible with IE 7 and 8, and if you say your suggestion isn't supported then it isn't usefull for my problem.

Comment: I meant HTML5 isnt supported in older versions of IE

Comment: What are you talking about? I requested a solution for image rotation that works with IE 7 + 8 and you edit your reply with a screenshot showing what the IEs don't support? I know that very well, what I don't know is a way to make an image rotate with IE 7 + 8, have you tried raphael in those browsers?