# IE: Expected identifier string or number

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, runtime-error

I've been at this for hours now. I've read about all sorts of common causes etc, but no solutions seem to work.

Site i'm working on:
http://goo.gl/UWyHB

Javascript file:
http://goo.gl/5kJkA

Feel free to test in IEX yourself. I'm testing with IETester on Windows 8, it's not stable at all and crashes on pretty much every page load.

I'm getting the following error in IE7-:

```
Line: 157
Char: 3
Error: Expected identifier string or number
Code: 0
```

I am assuming that's line 157 in the javascript file. I have the following around that line:

```
    /* Slide */
    $('.slider-wrapper .slider').animate({        <--- 154
        left: '-' + left
    }, slideSpeed);                               <--- 157

    // Scroll window to top
    var wrappos = $('.slider-wrapper').position().top - 20,
        docScrollTop = $('html').scrollTop() > $('body').scrollTop() ? $('html').scrollTop() : $('body').scrollTop();     <!--- 160
```

Any ideas? I had a comma after the "left" value, but removing it didn't do anything. I also tried wrapping the "left" key in quotes, no difference there either.

Any suggestions? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: i'm not getting any errors in IE

Comment: Im not testing but my first guess would be about the '-' + left, try removing the - for syntax's sake

Comment: I checked with Developer Tool in IE, and set the mode to IE7. The page loads without any error.

Comment: Worth looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612170/web-testing-for-ie-how-accurate-is-ietester

Comment: Oh. Maybe the cache just got stuck. Is the ie7-mode the same as the actual ie7 though, does it show the same errors etc? Is it possible to test IE6 also? @nhahtdh Yup, i've already read it :)